# significant figures in edittext

Tags: java, android

I have an `EditText` where the user enters a number.

Is there a way of setting the significant figures?
So it would automatically change `"003645"` to `"365"` at 3.s.f.

Comment: Text fields can be set to password, text, numbers etc... If you need to remove some part from the input the only way is to use java method for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
  // input, you have to read your EditText
  String input = "003645";    // your example
  int significantFigures = 3; // your example

  // calculation
  int number = Integer.parseInt(input, 10);
  int tooBig = (int) Math.pow(10, significantFigures);
  while (number > tooBig) {
      number = (int) Math.round(number / 10.0);
  }
  System.out.println(number); // prints 365
```

This will produce `1000` for input `001000` and `3` significant numbers. If it should produce `100` for the same input and significant amount of numbers you need to use greater or equals in the `while` condition.